What is the easiest way to migrate a crypto SaaS written in Rust, onto EVM compatible chains without rewriting everything completely?
one of our client websites https://odinbot.io has started on Solana network, all SOL projects are written in Rust and are a completely different language than Solidity, does anyone know of an efficient way of integrating our clients' entire Solana build with EVM compatible chains without rewriting everything completely?
Thank you in advance.
WE havent started this process yet because wed like to figure out if theres an easier way than rewriting everything in solidity to let them provide their SaS to EVM compatible chains.


does anyone know of an efficient way of integrating our clients' entire Solana build with EVM compatible chains without rewriting everything completely?

Because Solana and EVM have completely different architectures, you cannot port the code. A complete rewrite is needed.
